# Generating image wall from bottom up

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to build a virtual image wall where users can add a new brick to the top of the wall. So far I have used a float left to make all of the images wrap, but the problem with this is that it will be building from the top down and when a new brick is added it will add another brick to the bottom rather than the top.

This is what I currently have, but it's the wrong way, it needs to be inverted so brick 0 is at the bottom and if I add brick 31 it will be added to the top to create a stack.

[image]

I don't think the code matters much in this case, but here it is.

```php
<div id="wallwrapper">
<?php 
$brickrowclass = "";

for($i=0; $i <= 30; $i++)
{

    if($i % 10 == 0) 
    {
        if($brickrowclass == "std") $brickrowclass = "indent";
        else $brickrowclass = "std";
        echo "<div class='brickrow row{$brickrowclass}'>";
    }

    ?>
    <div class="brick">
    <span class="bricktitle">Brick <?php echo $i;?></span>
    </div>
    <?php   

    if($i % 10 == 0) echo "</div>";
}
?>
</div>
<style>
.brick{width:90px;height:40px;background-color: #AB4E4E;margin:1px;float:left;}
.brickrow{clear:both;}
.rowindent{margin-left:45px;}
#wallwrapper{width:1024px;}
</style>
```

Comment: When you add a brick... add it to the beginning instead...!?

Comment: show us some code ;)

Comment: @deceze not quite. See the way brick 30 as at the bottom on its own. I want this same behavior but upside down. So the bottom layer will fill first then build up rather than down

Comment: I see, so you want to build and "actual" wall brick by brick... Spontaneously I'd suggest you may be able to get somewhere pretty easily with `flex` layouts and `flex-wrap`; which is not supported by all browsers though. Otherwise you probably have no choice but to break out the Javascript. Or perhaps some trickery with rotating or flipping containers 180 degrees.

Comment: Since the width of the 'wall' and the bricks is known, you can calculate how  many bricks are in one row. and add new div on top when there is not enough place in the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in PHP but I created something similar in javascript. See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/a5hahvkd/

```
var numBricks = 31;
var bricksPerRow = 11;
var div;
for (var i = 0; i < numBricks; i++)
{
    if (i % bricksPerRow == 0)
    {
        div = $("<div/>").css('clear', 'both');
        $("#wallwrapper").prepend(div);
    }
    $(div).append('<div class="brick">Brick' + (i+1) + '</span></div>');
}
```

Since the width of the 'wall' and the bricks is known, you can calculate how many bricks are in one row. and add new div on top when there is not enough place in the row.

Play with 'numBricks' number and run it. I think this is what you want.

Comment: using javascript will result in a very slow page load when the wall gets huge, i can take this logic and try do something in php with it though

Comment: That is what I meant. Javascript was just the easiest way for me to demonstrate it. Taking it to PHP shouldn't be big problem.

Comment: Based on this logic i was able to generate each row as a php variable rather than echoing it out. I was then able to read through the array of rows backwards giving me the output that i wanted. thanks for the help